# Groovy help... About def edit and controllers

Tags: groovy, controller, dns, closures, edit

What does `def edit = {}` contain by default? You see, I was following a book but it turns out to be using an older version that's why some of the code don't work. I have this piece of code:

```
def edit= {
def user = User.get(params.id)
    if (session?.user?.id == null){
        flash.message = "You have to login first before editting your stuff."
        redirect(action:'login')
        return
    }else if(session?.user?.id != params.id) {
        flash.message = "You can only edit yourself."
        redirect(action:list)
        return
    }else{
        //What should I put here?
}

}
```

It's already functional. If the user clicks on edit without logging in, then he's redirected to a login page. Otherwise, if he did login, then he's only allowed to edit himself. What should I put on the "else" clause? It should already should already allow the user to edit his stuff, but I don't really know how to implement what I want. :(

It would be great if someone could share the default `edit` snippet.

I'm a bit new to all these, so go easy on me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about Grails, back up your UserController and try [grails generate-controller](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/generate-controller.html) - it will give you the complete text of default actions.

I also suggest that you look through [scaffolding chapter](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/16.%20Scaffolding.html) - it's a great point to start.

Comment: Thanks... :) I did what you said, it worked... But still something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

the default edit action should look like this (pseudo-code, it depends on the actual domain class you create the code upon):

```
def edit = {
    redirect(action: "show", id: params.id)
    return true

    def <domain>Instance = <DomainClass>.get(params.id)
    if (!<domain>Instance) {
        flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: '<DomainClass>.label', default: '<DomainClass>'), params.id])}"
        redirect(action: "list")
    }
    else {
        return [<domain>Instance: <domain>Instance]
    }
}
```

btw: most of the time you don't have to do the security checks by programming these explicitly in the controller code, check out the [Grails Spring Security Plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) for that purpose.